# Should spelling be corrected in quotes?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently responded to this question on gapless playback with Google Music:
[Google Music Gapless Playback](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/google-music-gapless-playback)

I quoted the response I got from Google Support, and made a remark that he probably didn't know what he was talking about because of how he spelled it. 
The spelling was corrected by another user, and the sentence no longer makes sense.

It originally said:

> He proceeded to refer to it as "gape less playback", so I don't know if
>   he actually has any idea what I'm talking about.

And was edited to say:

> He proceeded to refer to it as "gapless playback", so I don't know if
>   he actually has any idea what I'm talking about.

Should the original spelling be left alone, should the spelling be corrected, or should the sentence be removed completely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The faulty spelling is a part of your assumption that the Google support didn't really know what you were talking about. On the other hand you use it to make a statement that there's no gapless playback on Google Music.

In this particular case it is an integral part of your answer and it shouldn't have been altered. There is an option to rollback edits. Click on the red circled time/date notation:

[image]

and select rollback:

[image]

To clarify the second quote, I reviewed your answer to contain two quotes and added a reference to the grammar errors.

**Feel free to rollback !!**